# How to fix path variable in bash on Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal, .profile

This might be a noob question, but I need help. I screwed up my terminal by trying to alter my path variable using the following command:

`$ sudo nano .profile`

Before I did that, if I were to type:
`$ echo $PATH`

I would get: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

When I opened .profile in nano it told me that the file didn't exist. I figured that made sense, since I had never edited this file before. I proceeded to enter a path to a directory I was using for a php framework and saved the file.

After I saved the file, I noticed that none of my bash commands are working. Now I can't do anything from the terminal. I can't even edit .profile in nano because it says `-bash: nano: command not found`

I'm clearly new to working with the terminal. I feel completely lost. Please provide some guidance on how to restore the terminal to working condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use absolute paths.

```
 $  /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/nano .profile
```

If you add something to a path, never just do

```
 PATH=/path/to/something
```

instead do

```
 PATH=$PATH:/path/to/something
```

By the way, you shouldn't/don't have to use `sudo` to edit your own file, such as `.profile`. Use `sudo` only when you need to edit the file which doesn't to belong to your account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem!
The way I solved was writing the follow command in the terminal:
    PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Hope it can be useful for you